Series of prime numbers of the type $\sum\limits_ p \frac {(f(p)+P(p)) \mod (p)}{p^2}$
I am interested in series of this type: general question of such series with an interesting case shown here: particular interesting question. Intuitively such series converge as the heuristic argument goes that for big enough $n$ the nominator of the series will yield a number with an expectation of $n/2$ and $$\sum_ {n=1}^\infty \frac{(n/2)}{n^2}$$ diverges as a harmonic series. But now I want to take a look at series that go only through prime numbers. I had several attempts but the ones which catch my eye are of the type:
$$\sum_{p} \frac{(f(p)+P(p)) \mod(p)}{p^2}$$ where $f$ is a sum of exponentials in $p$ and $P$ is a polynomial in $p$. In this particular case, by using Wolfram Alpha, I get from a certain $p$ onto large numbers constant numerators making the above series converge. Here are 3 examples:

This series: $$\sum_ {p}\frac{(2^p-p^2+14p+31) \mod(p)}{p^2}$$ nominator yields $$\{1, 0, 3, 5, 0, 7, 16, 14, 10, 4, 2, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33\}.$$ I have checked up to the 500th prime number and $33$ is yielded up to there.

This series: $$\sum_ {p}\frac{(2^p-p^2+15p+27) \mod(p)}{p^2}$$ nominator yields $$\{1, 2, 4, 1, 7, 3, 12, 10, 6, 0, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29\}.$$ I have checked up to the 500th prime number and $29$ is yielded up to there.

This series: $$\sum_ {p}\frac{(2^p-p^2+16p+23) \mod(p)}{p^2}$$ nominator yields $$\{1, 1, 0, 4, 3, 12, 8, 6, 2, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25\}.$$ I have checked up to the 500th prime number and $25$ is yielded up to there.


So if from a certain number forward the sequence of number is constant the series is convergent.
I have also checked the cases $\mod(p)+1$ and $\mod(p^2)$. They do not get constant results.
Question:

How to prove that such sequence of numbers are constant from a point
on?

I have checked with ChatGPT 4o also. It has told me to ask a specialist. So here I am.

Actually by now, after looking a bit deeper, it seems to me that it is not that difficult. Fermat's little theorem helps with the exponential part and the polynomial part is divisible by p except for the free term. I hope I am on the right track.
